# Prove that if $|z|<1$, then $|z^2-z+i|<3$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that if $|z|<1$, then $|z^2-z+i|<3$. How can I prove this?

Comment: Think about the norms of $z^2$, $-z$, $i$ and triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z\in\Bbb C$. Then $z^2\in\Bbb C$. Note that $|i|=1$, $|-z|=|z|$, and $|z^2|=|z|^2$. Thus, using the Triangle Inequality
$$\begin{align}|z^2-z+i|&=|z^2+(-z)+i|\\
&\leq |z^2|+|-z|+|i|\\
&=|z|^2+|z|+1\\
&<1^2+1+1\\
&=3.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$$
${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$|z^2-z+i| \le |z|^2+|z|+1 <1+1+1=3$

Answer (score 0):

It's too easy just use triangle inequality and you will get the result.
$     |z² -z + i| ≤ |z²| + |z| + i$
$=> |z² -z + i| < 1+1+1$
$=> |z² -z + i| < 3$

Hence proved